# Display TimeStamp (Start Time/End Time) for each of the Test Scenario in Cucumber Report (.html/.json) file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, report

I am using a framework which generates JSON and cukes reports after the execution of UI
tests. 
I want to enhance the JSON and cukes reports with the start and end timestamps of
each of the UI tests (local time on your machine). For example, the following data should be
present in both reports:
Start time: 2019/10/23 11:22:33:456
End time: 2019/10/23 11:22:55:789

Can someone please help me with the same.

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add those two methods in one of your step classes:

```
@Before // io.cucumber.java.Before
public void logStartTime(Scenario scenario){
    scenario.write("Start time: " + new Date());    
}

@After // io.cucumber.java.After;
public void logEndTime(Scenario scenario){
    scenario.write("End time: " + new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just worth adding to the above comment, that you should add this in your hooks file (Be it hooks.js or .java or .rb or whatever language you are using).

This way you can have them fire on each scenario.